# Difference between weak Axiology, strong Axiology, weak Deontology, and strong Deontology

Tags: ethics, deontology, axiology

Axiology is the philosophical study of value. However, I don't see what strong Axiology and weak Axiology mean. The same thing with strong Deontology and weak Deontology. I can't seem to find the definitions anywhere.